# how to use terraform output to deploy image inside kubernetes cluster in modular approch?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, kubectl, hcl

well, I'm new in terraforming and also in Kubernetes, I faced an issue in deploying images after creating a Kubernetes cluster.

I have created a module that creates a Kubernetes cluster and provides output for the Kube config data.
now I'm using the code below but i need to run terraform apply 2 times because first time the local file is not created and terraform could not connect to kubernetes or helm or kubectl but if i run the command twice it works as expected.

any solution?

---

**Note: i also applied the solution as on the comment section of the
code and that comment did now work either.**

---

> File : main.tf

```
module "deploy_lke" {
      source             = "./modules/linode/kubernetes"
      token              = var.token
      k8s_version        = var.k8s_version
      label              = var.label
      region             = var.region
      tags               = var.tags
      instance_type      = var.instance_type
      number_of_instance = var.number_of_instance
      min                = var.min
      max                = var.max
    
    }
    
    module "deploy_image" {
      source           = "./modules/kubernetes"
      kube_config_path = module.deploy_lke.kubeconfig
      dockerconfigjson = file("./secret/docker-sec.json")
      deploy_name      = var.deploy_name
      desire_replicas  = var.desire_replicas
      image_link       = var.image_link
      image_name       = var.image_name
      image_port       = var.image_port
      ip_type          = var.ip_type
      max_replicas_val = var.max_replicas_val
      min_replicas_val = var.min_replicas_val
      service_name     = var.service_name
    
    }
```

File : ./module/linode/kubernetes

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    linode = {
      source  = "linode/linode"
      version = "1.29.4"
    }
    kubernetes = {
      source  = "hashicorp/kubernetes"
      version = ">= 2.0.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "linode" {
  token = var.token
}

resource "linode_lke_cluster" "gaintplay-web-lke" {
  k8s_version = var.k8s_version
  label       = var.label
  region      = var.region
  tags        = var.tags


  pool {
    type  = var.instance_type
    count = var.number_of_instance
    autoscaler {
      min = var.min
      max = var.max
    }
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      pool.0.count
    ]
  }
}

output "kubeconfig" {
  value     = linode_lke_cluster.gaintplay-web-lke.kubeconfig
}


output "api_endpoints" {
  value = linode_lke_cluster.gaintplay-web-lke.api_endpoints
}
```

File : ./module/kubernetes

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    kubernetes = {
      source  = "hashicorp/kubernetes"
      version = ">= 2.0.0"
    }
  }
}
resource "local_file" "kube_config_file" {
    content  = var.kube_config_path
    filename = "${path.module}/config"
}
provider "kubernetes" {
  config_path = var.kube_config_path
}
provider "helm" {
  kubernetes {
    config_path = var.kube_config_path
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_secret" "docker_secret" {
  metadata {
    name = "docker-cfg"
  }

  data = {
    ".dockerconfigjson" = var.dockerconfigjson
  }

  type = "kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson"
}


resource "kubernetes_deployment" "beta" {
  depends_on = [
    kubernetes_secret.docker_secret
  ]
  metadata {
    name      = var.deploy_name
    namespace = "default"
  }
  spec {
    replicas = var.desire_replicas
    selector {
      match_labels = {
        app = var.deploy_name
      }
    }
    template {
      metadata {
        labels = {
          app = var.deploy_name
        }
      }
      spec {
        image_pull_secrets {
          name = kubernetes_secret.docker_secret.metadata[0].name
        }
        container {
          image_pull_policy = "Always"
          image             =  var.image_link
          name              = var.image_name
          port {
            container_port = var.image_port
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
# provider "kubernetes" {
#     host = "${yamldecode(var.kube_config_path).clusters.0.cluster.server}"
#     client_certificate = "${base64decode(yamldecode(var.kube_config_path).users.0.user.client-certificate-data)}"
#     client_key = "${base64decode(yamldecode(var.kube_config_path).users.0.user.client-key-data)}"
#     cluster_ca_certificate = "${base64decode(yamldecode(var.kube_config_path).clusters.0.cluster.certificate-authority-data)}"
# }
# provider "helm" {
#   kubernetes {
#    host = "${yamldecode(var.kube_config_path).clusters.0.cluster.server}"
#     client_certificate = "${base64decode(yamldecode(var.kube_config_path).users.0.user.client-certificate-data)}"
#     client_key = "${base64decode(yamldecode(var.kube_config_path).users.0.user.client-key-data)}"
#     cluster_ca_certificate = "${base64decode(yamldecode(var.kube_config_path).clusters.0.cluster.certificate-authority-data)}"
#   }
# }
```

If i use the command as it is i got this error in terraform plan that the file is not found  and i need to run it twice.

```
Invalid attribute in provider configuration

  with module.deploy_image.provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/kubernetes"],
  on modules/kubernetes/main.tf line 13, in provider "kubernetes":
  13:     provider "kubernetes" {

'config_path' refers to an invalid path: "modules/kubernetes/config": stat modules/kubernetes/config: no such file or directory
```

and

If I use commented code i get error like this:

```
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on main.tf line 35, in provider "kubernetes":
│   35:     host = "${yamldecode(linode_lke_cluster.gaintplay-web-lke.kubeconfig).clusters.0.cluster.server}"
│ 
│ Can't access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string).
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on main.tf line 36, in provider "kubernetes":
│   36:     client_certificate = "${base64decode(yamldecode(linode_lke_cluster.gaintplay-web-lke.kubeconfig).users.0.user.client-certificate-data)}"
│ 
│ Can't access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string).
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this `yamldecode(var.kube_config_path)` will not work. What is the value that `kube_config_path` should have?

Comment: ya it didn't work and I finally create a bash script to fully automate all my deployments....  terraform still does not support complex orchestration. that's why I need a bash script with terraforming.